# Import OWL ontology rdf/xml format into OrientDB Graph Database

Tags: xml, graph, rdf, orientdb, owl

I am working with OWL ontology in RDF/XML format and I would to import it into OrientDB graph database.
Is it a possibility to convert the OWL into GraphML and import it in OrientDB through GraphSail?

I understood that GraphML is the only format that OrientDB can load a graph file in XML format. Is it right?

Comment: Why now GraphML? Again you would have to map OWL to GraphML as there is no standard conversion specified. What about your previous question where you wanted to convert OWL to OrientDB format?

Comment: @AKSW I saw that OrientDB can read GraphML (https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Import-from-Neo4j-using-GraphML.html). So I thought to convert OWL ontology in RDF/XML format to GraphML as described here http://organizingknowledge.blogspot.it/2014/05/diagramming-rdfxml-owl-ontology.html. The XSLTs for the conversion is here https://github.com/NinePts/OntoGraph. What do you think?